# Анимация slide button

Tags: android, анимация

У меня есть следущая анимация

```
<translate
   android:fromXDelta="0"
   android:toXDelta="100"
   android:duration="300"
/>
```

Которая сдвигает мою кнопку вправо, при этом сдвиге слева становиться виден фон так как кнопка не растягивается, а просто сдвигается.  Пробовал играться с масштабированием,но толком ничего не получилось. Думал поставить на то место которое оголяется при сдвиге поставить подложку такого же цвета как кнопка,но это на крайняк. Может есть какой товариат обычной анимацией сделать эффект слайдера. Вот пример картинка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть возможность спрятать часть кнопки под дочерний layout, тогда будет проще подобрать цвет и не волноваться о тенях и тд, более того можно использовать группу элементов, что тоже упрощает элемент отрисовки. Эффект будет интересный. Ниже пример разметки, вы добавьте эффект на любую кнопку и увидите результат.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_1"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <Button
        android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Push"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:gravity="center|end"
        android:onClick="Cclickbtn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Me"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:gravity="center|end"
        android:onClick="Cclickbtn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
        android:layout_width="241dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hard"
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:gravity="center|end"
        android:onClick="Cclickbtn" />
</LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: т.е.  основная задумка в том что бы сделать кнопку заведомо больше на величину сдвига и на эту же величину сдвинуть ее по оси Х влево,  правильно?

Comment: Не обязательно на эту величину сдвигать, можете сделать запас. Ведь анимация можеть быть сильней и тогда кнопка вылезет, нужно учитывать ещё интеполяторы анимаций, поэтому просто сделайте небольшой запас и будет счастье

Comment: да, как вариант подходит, просто тогда с позиционированием текста надо подстраиваться так как сейчас я его по центру кнопки выставляю.

Comment: Очень легко сдвиньте на столько же, на сколько задвигаете под layout